# Can't delete foreign key (Oracle)

Tags: oracle, jdbc, foreign-keys, constraints

I'm trying to delete all foreign keys of a table. First I get all the names of those keys using `meta.getExportedKeys(null, null, table);` and `rs.getString("FK_NAME")`.

But when I try to delete this key using:

```
ALTER TABLE tablename DROP CONSTRAINT fkname
```

it only works for some keys. Sometimes I'm getting:

```
ORA-02443: Cannot drop constraint - nonexistent constraint
```

But the foreign key is definitely there. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have you tried

```
ALTER TABLE tablename DROP CONSTRAINT "fkname";
```

instead?

You might have created the constraint in a case-sensitive way, in which case, you'll need to put the constraint name in double quotes when you drop it.  Here's an example session in SQL*Plus:

```
SQL> create table test (a integer);

Table created.

SQL> alter table test add constraint "abcd" unique (a);

Table altered.

SQL> alter table test drop constraint abcd;
alter table test drop constraint abcd
                                 *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-02443: Cannot drop constraint  - nonexistent constraint


SQL> alter table test drop constraint "abcd";

Table altered.

SQL>
```

Comment: The other possibility is that the table that owns the constraint is in a different schema. Eg schema FRED contains tables 'A' and 'B' and that a constraint on 'B' points to a table 'A' owned by FREDA